# How do I round off a 'Float' object?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rounding

I am trying to return the percentage rounded to one decimal place from a database using pandas.

my code consists of:

```py
df.loc[((df['education-num'] < 13)|(df['education'] == 'Prof-school')) & (df['salary'] == '>50K')].shape[0] / df.loc[(df['education-num'] < 13)| (df['education'] == 'Prof-school')].shape[0]*100)
```

which returns:

> 17.3713601914639

The correct answer is

> 17.4

so I just need to round it up

If I use `.round(1)`:

```
 (df.loc[((df['education-num'] < 13)|(df['education'] == 'Prof-school')) & (df['salary'] == '>50K')].shape[0]/ df.loc[(df['education-num'] < 13)| (df['education'] == 'Prof-school')].shape[0]*100).round(1)
```

I get: `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'round'`

How can I round it up one decimal place?

Comment: wrap your output in `round` as opposed to trying to call `round` on it like a method/attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the round function to the value you're extracting.

```
number = df.loc[((df['education-num'] < 13)|(df['education'] == 'Prof-school')) & (df['salary'] == '>50K')].shape[0]/ df.loc[(df['education-num'] < 13)| (df['education'] == 'Prof-school')].shape[0]*100

rounded = round(number,1)
```

Answer (score 2):

[`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) is a global function, not a method of `float`.

```
print(round(17.3713601914639, 1))
```

If you really want to round **up only**, use [`math.ceil()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.ceil), which unfortunately does not take an additional argument for the decimal to be rounded, so you need to consider that yourself

```
import math
def round_up(number:float, digits:int):
  return math.ceil(number * 10**digits) / 10**digits

print(round_up(17.31, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the float to the round() function, like so:

```
x = 3.1415927

print(round(x, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(round(17.3713601914639, 1))
```